# URL of background-image embeded in a div class of a BS4 element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am not an expert in web scraping, but I managed to get most of what I want. However, I am finding a hard time parsing the last part of my code, a background image.

This is what I have:

```
htmlSource.find('div', class_='flex-embed-content flex-embed-cover-image ')
```

Which returns:

```
<div class="flex-embed-content flex-embed-cover-image " style="background-image: url('//site.org/photos/0/kp/cr/QOKPCRqjkbbldlo-400x225-noPad.jpg?1528717310')"></div>
```

I am interedted in the URL `//site.org/photos/0/kp/cr/QOKPCRqjkbbldlo-400x225-noPad.jpg?1528717310`

How can I parse it from htmlSource?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the style attribute and use string manipulation. Example method below (clearly there are others)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''<div class="flex-embed-content flex-embed-cover-image " style="background-image: url('//site.org/photos/0/kp/cr/QOKPCRqjkbbldlo-400x225-noPad.jpg?1528717310')"></div>'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

item = soup.select_one('div.flex-embed-content.flex-embed-cover-image')
item['style'].split("url('")[1][:-3]
```

Note I am using select_one as there is a single match based on the html put in. You can use select with a selector including the style attribute `div.flex-embed-content.flex-embed-cover-image[style]` and a loop. I would also see if you can reduce the number of classes used in the selector.

Comment: This is not ideal, as with the `split` you cannot ensure it keeps working if the website changes this `div` adding another element on style, before the url. 
For this reason, regex is generally ideal for those situations:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934372/10642035

Comment: @LuanNaufal    I'd agree. I would write one but you've beaten me to it! +

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should get your `div` element, and there are many ways to do so, but since you have a really specific class, it suffices (here assuming your html code is stored in the `htmlSource` variable:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource, "html.parser")
divElement = soup.select_one('div.flex-embed-content.flex-embed-cover-image')
```

Now you should take the `style` attribute, and filter it for the url, and I suggest using regex, and this way you won't have an issue with unexpected elements added to the style overtime:

```
pattern = r"(?<=url\().*(?='\))"
url = re.search(pattern, divElement["style"]).group(0) # The group(0) is used to recover the whole match
```

The `(?<=TEXT_BEFORE)` content in regex, assumes that our match starts with this TEXT_BEFORE content, but doesn't include it in the match (*lookbegind assertion*), and the `(?=TEXT_AFTER)` tells the opposite, and only matches if the match follows by TEXT_AFTER (*lookahead assertion*)

So the full code would be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
divElement = soup.select_one('div.flex-embed-content.flex-embed-cover-image')

pattern = r"(?<=url\().*(?='\))"
url = re.search(pattern, divElement["style"]).group(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the solution is using `urlextract`. This class help to find url in string .

**Implementation:**

```
from urlextract import URLExtract
```

**Usage:**

```
extractor = URLExtract()
```

**Code:**

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
finddiv = htmlSource.find('div', class_='flex-embed-content flex-embed-cover-image')

style = finddiv['style']

for url in extractor.gen_urls(style):

    print (url)
    print('----')
    print('//'+url)
```

OUTPUT :

```
site.org/photos/0/kp/cr/QOKPCRqjkbbldlo-400x225-noPad.jpg?1528717310
----
//site.org/photos/0/kp/cr/QOKPCRqjkbbldlo-400x225-noPad.jpg?1528717310
```

Comment: TypeError: find() takes no keyword arguments

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute contains CSS, which is something beautifulsoup does not know how to parse.

So first thing - get the style attribute content. Now you need to parse the CSS. You can parse it yourself (look for `url(...)`), which will work if the site doesn't change much.

Another option is to use a dedicated CSS parser, such as [tinycss](https://tinycss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parsing.html#quickstart). I would use a CSS parser, your code will be more resilient to site changes.

Comment: This looks very interesting. Does it have to have the entire page? Or can an example be shown in relation to the problem above?

Comment: You can actually do it with BS4 easily, only searching based on classes and getting the style:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934372/10642035

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner in web scraping, here is the solution to your problem.

```
first=htmlSource.find('div', class_='flex-embed-content flex-embed-cover-image ')
get_style=first['style']
break_url=get_style.split(':')
break_url=break_url[1]
break_url=break_url.split("'")
final_url=break_url(1)
```

Comment: This is not a good reply, as if the website changes the logic inside the style, it might stop working (such as adding another style element before the url). 
For this reason I always prefer to use regex on those situations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934372/10642035